# How to merge a 64 by 64 cell into a 1 by 1 cell

Tags: matlab

I have a 64 by 64 cell and how do I merge it back into a 1 by 1 cell? Each cell is a 8 by 8 double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html).

```
%# create a sample 2-by-2 cell array
c = cell(2);

%# put a 3-by-3 double into each cell
[c{:}] = deal(magic(3));

%# convert to one big 6-by-6 array
m = cell2mat(c);
```

**EDIT**

If you want the result to be a cell again, run

```
m = {cell2mat(c)};
```